# Something seems to fail after 1622 characters(null values)

Tags: php

I'm having this issue with the JSONAPI for minecraft. http://mcjsonapi.com/

I am trying to use the method "files.write" or "setFileContents" to replace the contents of a file. The website states [this](http://mcjsonapi.com/apidocs/#files.write) about the method.

Pretty simple. Just rewrites the file right? Yeah but this is proving to be more difficult then I thought. At first attempt, I was trying to set [3450 characters](http://hastebin.com/igaqemesoh.sm) to the file "groups.yml" on the minecraft server. Here's the code I ran in PHP:

```
var_dump(
    $api->call("files.write", array("plugins/GroupManager/worlds/world/groups.yml", (string)$yaml))
);
```

The var_dump is supposed to either return a success statement or an error describing what went wrong. But instead all I get is "null". This isn't right, and I know $yaml is being casted to a string, which isn't the issue. So I decide to start testing around. After much testing, I find that the character length of what I can set is exactly 1622. Adding another space or anything causes null, otherwise, it works. [This](http://hastebin.com/ulohomulog.sm) is the modified file that is below 1622 characters I tested with.

So great, you found the issue, right? No, I didn't. I thought 1622 was an odd number to stop working, so I did some further testing. I tried to set 3000 characters I generated from just smashing my keyboard, and it worked! So what's going on here?

[This](http://hastebin.com/kaxekemabu.hs) and [this](http://hastebin.com/ulohomulog.sm) works, but [this doesn't](http://hastebin.com/ecofejonag.sm). Why is this? This app called [Adminium](https://adminiumapp.com/) runs this exact API, and includes a file management system inside the app which I am assuming uses the same methods I am using, but it doesn't have a problem.

I have a [forum post here](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/297659-converting-variable-into-a-string/) that I also asked on, and still haven't gotten to an answer yet.

Comment: If the function is returning null then you should report it as a bug to the authors because according to the documentation it should either return a boolean or throw an exception.

Comment: I cannot believe I haven't done that yet. Anyways I just emailed the author and posted a bug report on github.